# System.ArgumentException: „Column does not belong to table .” - how to fix this error (import data from csv file to mysql database)?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datatable, argumentexception

In this case I'd like to import data from csv file to mysql database. For now i've written method which inserts that file:

1) Select file with extension "*.csv"

2) After select it loads data by dividing commas and continuing if are empty cells.

```
        private DataTable ImportFile()
        {
            DataTable imported_data = new DataTable();

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Open csv file";
            ofd.DefaultExt = "*.csv";
            ofd.Filter = "Documents (*.csv)|*.csv";
            ofd.ShowDialog();

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
            string FileName1 = ofd.FileName;
            string excel = fi.FullName;

            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(excel))
            {
                string header = sr.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not found or loaded not correct file.");
                    return null;
                }

                string[] header_columns = header.Split(',');
                foreach(string header_column in header_columns)
                {
                    imported_data.Columns.Add(header_column);
                }

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linia)) continue;

                    string[] fields = line.Split(',');
                    DataRow imported_row = imported_data.NewRow();

                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        imported_row[i] = fields[i];
                    }

                    imported_data.Rows.Add(imported_row);
                }
            }
            return imported_data;
        }
```

Then the second method is when it has a connection with mysql database it inserts values to that database:

```
private void save_modules(DataTable imported_data)
{
    string connection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection))
    {
        conn.Open();
        foreach (DataRow importRow in imported_data.Rows)
        {
            string query3 = @"INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.modules (NAME, ID_PROJECT) SELECT @NAME, projekty.ID 
                FROM try1.projects WHERE projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME;";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query3, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", importRow["NAME"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", importRow["PROJECT_NAME"]);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }  
    MessageBox.Show("Imported to database");
}
```

And event when clicks to btn_import_projects.

```
    private void btn_import_projects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataTable imported_data = ImportFile();
            save_modules(imported_data);
            frm2.loaddataalldatagridview();      
    }
```

when I compiled connected from 3 codes lines to 1 code i had an exception error:

> System.ArgumentException: „Column NAME does not belong to table .”

And shows at the line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", importRow["NAME"]);
```

I have a question how to fix this error? Should i change the code lines form `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` to `cmd.Parameters.Add`? Any ideas? Thx in advance.

**UPDATE**

for the case for only 1 column the code:

```
private void save_projects(DataTable imported_data)
{
    string connection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection))
    {
        conn.Open();
        foreach (DataRow importRow in imported_data.Rows)
        {
                string query2 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.projects(PROJECT_NAME) VALUES (@PROJECT_NAME);";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query2, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", importRow["PROJECT_NAME"]);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }  
    MessageBox.Show("Imported to database");
}
```

It works without any small error.

There is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ControlDataBase
{
    public partial class Import_data_mysql : Form
    {
        public Import_data_mysql()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        New_Tables frm2 = (New_Tables)Application.OpenForms["New_Tables"];

        private DataTable ImportFile()
        {
            DataTable imported_data = new DataTable();

            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Open csv file";
            ofd.DefaultExt = "*.csv";
            ofd.Filter = "Documents (*.csv)|*.csv";
            ofd.ShowDialog();

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
            string FileName1 = ofd.FileName;
            string excel = fi.FullName;

            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(excel))
            {
                string header = sr.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not found or loaded not correct file.");
                    return null;
                }

                string[] header_columns = header.Split(',');
                foreach(string header_column in header_columns)
                {
                    imported_data.Columns.Add(header_column);
                }

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;

                    string[] fields = line.Split(',');
                    DataRow imported_row = imported_data.NewRow();

                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        imported_row[i] = fields[i];
                    }

                    imported_data.Rows.Add(imported_row);
                }
            }
            return imported_data;
        }

        private void save_modules(DataTable imported_data)
        {
            string connection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection))
            {
                conn.Open();
                foreach (DataRow importRow in imported_data.Rows)
                {
                    string query3 = @"INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.modules (NAME, ID_PROJECT) SELECT @NAME, projekty.ID 
                        FROM try1.projects WHERE projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME;";

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query3, conn);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", importRow["NAME"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", importRow["PROJECT_NAME"]);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }  
            MessageBox.Show("Imported to database");
        }

        private void btn_import_projects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable imported_data = ImportFile();
                save_modules(imported_data);
                frm2.loaddataalldatagridview();
            }

            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select invalid file to import data.");
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `imported_data.Columns.Add(header)` should be `imported_data.Columns.Add(header_column)`. That's why the columns you're looking for aren't in there, the entire header string is added over and over again

Comment: ok @soohoonigan you're right i've edited it but still it has no effect which i'd like to achieve, Do you have any idea?

Comment: The rest of the code looks OK to me at a glance...if you're still getting the same error then put a break-point after you parse the column header names and take a look to make sure that uppercase NAME and PROJECT_NAME are in the Columns collection

Comment: But what kind "Columns collection"? These NAME and PROJECT_NAME are in Columns collection (in csv file). Only NAME is in "modules" database table and PROJECT_NAME in "projects" database table.

Comment: Not in the csv file, I mean the `imported_data.Columns` collection. Put a breakpoint after you add all the header_column values to the imported_data.columns collection, hover your mouse over the collection, and make sure the column names you are referencing later (i.e. "NAME" and "PROJECT_NAME") are in there and have been parsed properly

Comment: I've just put breakpoint at `imported_data.Columns` and me thinks that these columns are in collection. Where the name is "header_column" it shows the values: "NAME;PROJECTNAME".

Comment: Well then there's the problem, they are separated by a semicolon `;` bur you are splitting the headers by a comma `,`. `string[] header_columns = header.Split(',')` should be `string[] header_columns = header.Split(';')` and `importRow["PROJECT_NAME"]` should be `importRow["PROJECTNAME"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196218/discussion-between-prochu1991-and-soohoonigan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Responding to @soohoonigan advice I had to change only two lines of code:

```
string[] header_columns = header.Split(',');
string[] fields = line.Split(',');
```

After finding out that in .csb file is seperated with these ";" signs so i've changed these lines to this:

```
string[] header_columns = header.Split(';');
string[] fields = line.Split(';');
```

And works correctly. Thanks a alot mates. :)